# Blazor Dynamic Custom Elements in application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a webapp built in C# with Blazor WASM that is Asp.Net hosted. I'm making a blazor component that through the use of a library already in production, will generate a HTML fragment (or full embed) that is then displayed in this way

```
...
    <div>
        @((MarkupString)document)
    </div>
...
```

with `document` containing the markup generated by the library.

As long as we're doing it with static content all is fine and dandy, but now we need to have some input in there that will then be sent back to the server to execute some actions.

In a `MarkupString` there is no way to include `<InputFile />` or `<InputText />` components in such a way that they are shown in the fragment and I can read their contents, and I can find no way to actually interact with the standard HTML tags, especially regarding the file upload.

Moreover we'll probably soon need to have a specific image uploader with preview which would be a custom Blazor component and this led me to the CustomElements .NET 7 feature that looks like what I need for both problems.

However I couldn't find how to actually implement this in my app, and the documentation I found is still very partial in that way. Is there a way to do what I need?

EDIT: Managed to fix this partially, with Chen's answer. I still have trouble with the binding though, as the `@bind-Value` directive is not working with

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputText requires a value for the 'ValueExpression' parameter. Normally this is provided automatically when using 'bind-Value'.
```

with this markup:

```
...
<custom-input-text @bind-value="$field1" name="$field1"></custom-input-text>
...
```

(the capital V in bind-Value becomes lowercase all by itself)

Am I doing something wrong again?

Comment: Is your library generating a string or a `RenderFragment`?

Comment: A string with a complete HTML page with its own style and all. I can strip things and make it render as a `div`, kind of, or I can use it as is. Would enclosing the HTML in a `RenderFragment` help?

Comment: Two questions: [Polite] Do you know what a `RenderFragment` really is? Is there a reason why you generate your page as a string rather than as a RenderFragment?

Comment: Kind-of but apparently not well enough haha, I'm looking into them since I read your comment. About the generator, it's a "quasi-legacy" library and works pretty well, so I wanted to avoid operating any change there (if not necessary, I mean)

Comment: I marked it as polite because you could have taken it the wrong way which was not my intent.  I have been found guilty many times over of "Kind-of but apparently not well enough".  There's some resources of mine about components here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Components/blob/master/Documents/A-Deep-Dive-into-the-Component/index.md

Comment: When you say "standard HTML tags" it looks like you mean Components (such as `InputText`).  Binding is a Razor directive that builds mappings in the actual compiled C# code.  Try writing some test code and then viewing the compiled C# file.  To view the compiled files see https://gist.github.com/ShaunCurtis/0a487f4d0970267f871bea5ef77e4e42.

Comment: Do you have a dummy "document" with some pseudo markup in it?

Comment: No worries, I understood about the "polite" warning :) I said standard HTML tags is because of the `CustomElements` approach I used, so that I can use, for example, `<custom-input-file>` to generate a `<InputFile>` component through the use of `builder.RootComponents.RegisterCustomElement<InputFile>("custom-input-file");`. The only issue I have is that I can't seem to trigger a binding/callback for these in any way. The dummy document question: if you mean whether I can provide one, well of course :) here is an example original/blazorified file https://pastebin.com/u/marcus905/1/nxjY0yGh

Answer (score 0):

`CustomElements` should meet your requirements, you can create your own logic in Blazor components, and then use it in your application.

To use the component, you need to add the following JavaScript script references to your host app in this specific order.

```
<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements/BlazorCustomElements.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

You also need to add the corresponding middleware:

```
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
```

And use `app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();` for debugging.

Then you need to register the corresponding component in the Blazor program:

```
builder.RootComponents.RegisterCustomElement<Counter>("my-counter");
```

Then you can call this component in your application, including passing parameters, etc.

```
<my-counter title="Khalid" increment-amount="2" />
```

Here is a [complete example with detailed explanation](https://github.com/khalidabuhakmeh/BlazorCustomElementsSample), you can use it as a reference.

Helpful links:

[Blazor Custom Elements](https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/main/src/BlazorCustomElements).

[Using .NET 7's Blazor Custom Elements to render dynamic content](https://jonhilton.net/blazor-custom-elements/).

[ASP.NET Core Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#blazor-custom-elements).

Hope this can help you.

**Edit1:**

It looks like you can't do two-way binding between `Razor Page` and `Razor Component`. The [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#pass-parameters) mentions that parameters can be passed through JavaScript properties, but it doesn't seem to be able to read the parameters.

For example：

```
<my-counter ></my-counter>
<button onclick="Test()">click</button>

<script>
    function Test()
    {
        const elem = document.querySelector("my-counter");
        //get parameter failed, it's undefined
        var text = elem.incrementAmount;
        //successfully set parameter 
        elem.incrementAmount = "test";
    }
</script>
```

So I'm guessing that CustomElements only have writable properties in Razor Page.

**Edit2:**

I found that JQuery can be used to detect the value of the input box. When getting this value and performing certain operations, can it also achieve the same effect as two-way binding?

```
<my-counter ></my-counter>
<button onclick="Test()">click</button>

<script>
    function Test()
    {
        const elem = document.querySelector("my-counter");
        //get the value of input
        var value = $("my-counter").find("input").val();
        elem.incrementAmount = "test";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Chen, I tried that but I have problems with the `builder.RootComponents` part, but the example is very helpful. Since my Custom Elements are not really custom but are a dynamic rendering of builtin elements, do you think I have to do a custom "shim" (if we can call it that) to wrap the custom elements in?

Comment: Additionally, regarding the example you linked (that I concur: it's very useful) the host application is a classic Razor application, not a Blazor Webassembly one, while I'm already trying to make it work in that way, do you thin I have to consider something more because of this?

Comment: Hi @marcus905, do you mean that your "custom element" will actually autofill some data? You can execute the corresponding logic in the component. In fact, the essence of `CustomElements` is to display it and perform some interactions? What exactly does "consider something more" refer to?

Comment: Hi, the opposite: I want my custom element to be able to return some data back to me (or read its contents) programmatically, as I would with the `@bind` directive in a standard component.